# Submit form but user's input remain

Tags: php, html, forms

How to keep user's input after they submit a form?

For example:

```
<form action="a.php" method="POST">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

    echo $firstname.$lastname; 
?>
```

if user key in fname and lname, yes, it will echo out.. but i wan to keep their first name and last name at the input type, so that user dont need to refill again if the form is long.

Comment: utilize `value` attributes to set the value after the form have been submitted. a simple ternary should suffice, `<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : ''; ?>">` like so

Comment: @Ghost or the PHP7 way: `echo $_POST['lastname'] ?? '';`

Comment: @Mike still maintaining pre php7 codebase, how i wish i can use these new ones

Comment: @Ghost I hear you! Good thing PHP 5.6 will be past its EOL the end of the year, so maybe then you could update your codebase.

Comment: try using browser autocomplete by adding attribute to form like autocomplete=on

<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

and for particular if you want to put autocomplete off you can do that as i did in email above e.g

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your form sticky so that the user does not need to fill the entire form again which is a good practice.

You can add `value` to your form inputs for your form example like shown below:

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) echo $_POST['firstname'];?>" />
 <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) echo $_POST['lastname'];?>" />
```

In the similar way, you can make your entire form sticky (different for textarea and others but the similar idea).